# Custom pipe is not working

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I did implement custom pipe that getting array of objects and then filter this array accroding to user input. But if I'm using element reference instead of [(ngModel)], it's not working.
Here is input element and pipe:

```
<input class="form-control ml-1" type="text" placeholder="Найти запчасть по названию" #search>
```

...

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of currentModel | searchPipe: search.value">
```

And here is pipe itself.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: CatalogueShortDto[], args?: any): any {
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(args) && args.length > 0) {
      return value.filter(search => {
        return search.bluePrintCode.includes(args) || search.sparePartName.includes(args);
      });
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Even breakpoints in pipe wasn't fired. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you actually declared and exported the pipe?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, of course, otherwise there will be compilation error.

Comment: <input (input)="0" will raise change detection

Comment: @yurzui, nope, it's not working

Comment: @yurzui, you're almost right. (keyup) did it. You may add this as answer.

Comment: It should work with `(input)` it will also work if you paste some piece of code in input by using mouse https://plnkr.co/edit/bacEQxisRhcBZjTAqhgd?p=preview

Comment: Just FYI ... the documentation also strongly suggests *against* using a pipe for filtering unless you are sure you have a very small set of data or don't care about performance. See this link: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe I have some sample code for how to filter in your component instead. Let me know if you'd like me to post it here.

Comment: @DeborahK, sure, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable

> Angular updates the bindings (and therefore the screen) only if the
>   app does something in response to asynchronous events, such as
>   keystrokes. This example code binds the keyup event to the number 0,
>   the shortest template statement possible. While the statement does
>   nothing useful, it satisfies Angular's requirement so that Angular
>   will update the screen.

So you can use either

```
<input (input)="0"
```

or

```
<input (keyup)="0"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bacEQxisRhcBZjTAqhgd?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Filtering in code ... Just bind to filteredProducts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    errorMessage: string;
    filteredProducts: IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

    }

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
              product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts()
                .subscribe(products => {
                    this.products = products;
                    this.filteredProducts = this.products;
                },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```